# stuck in the mud -- trying to install new MacOS from USB

Tags: macos, usb, install

I have an iMac with a blank hard drive.  The HD has been erased and formatted using the Disk Utility.  Now I want to install MacOS -- any MacOS.

When I try to install High Sierra from a 16 GB USB drive, it appears to work but then stalls with "2 minutes remaining".  The bar is at about three-quarters. The pop-up message says: "An error occurred while preparing the installation". 
 There is no error number or further explanation.  This has happened three times.  The same USB was used to successfully upgrade another iMac of the same model, but that one had El Capitan installed first.  Anybody care to offer a guess as to what is happening?

So, I guess I need to create another bootable USB drive.  Perhaps El Capitan will work better?  Before you ask, my iMac is definitely compatible with High Sierra.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the model of iMac in question to your question.

Comment: Along with @SteveChambers suggestion, if it is newer, you should first try the internet recovery option, but we don't know your model yet.

Comment: How do you determine the model of a machine that has no OS installed?  I do know that it is too old to use Alt-Control-R for Internet recovery, but not too old to handle High Sierra.

Comment: You can find the model by looking up the serial number here: https://www.powerbookmedic.com/identify-mac-serial.php. The serial number is printed on the bottom of the base.

Comment: Since my original post, I've done the following:

Comment: Since my original post, I've done the following:  1,  Erased the USB with High Sierra install,   2.  Created a bootable USB for El Capitan using DiskMaker X,   3.  Booted with the new USB and attempted installation.  It got all the way to "about 1 second remaining, then it sat there for 15 to 30 minutes before finally displaying "an error occurred in the preparation".   4.  Performed First Aid on the target volume -- of course it passed.  Next:  If the model is really important, I can try to find an electron microscope to pull it off the bottom of the stand.

Comment: Model is A1311.  Now I'm installing El Capitan for the third time.  Because I'm insane, I'm hoping for a different result this time.  Is it possible that I have a problem with the internal hard disk?  Is there a way to get Disk Utility to perform a sector-by-sector surface test?

Comment: Does anybody have a suggestion?  Something I haven't already tried?